# How to test the args passed into document.body.appendChild with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function that creates a script element and adds it to the body. It looks a bit like this:

```js
const s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'https://myscript';
s.id = 'abc';

document.body.appendChild(s);
```

I'm using testing using jest and am spying on the `appendChild` function to assert that the parameters passed in are what I expect. What I have looks like this:

```js
jest.spyOn(document.body, 'appendChild');

doFunction();

expect(document.body.appendChild).toBeCalledWith(
  '<script id="abc" src="https://myscript" type="text/javascript" />',
);
```

Despite the strings matching, the argument that gets passed into `appendChild` isn't a string, but an object.

```
typeof document.body.appendChild.mock.child[0][0] // object
```

I've also tried asserting against an object (`{ type: '...' }` with no luck. What other options are there with jest to test this bit of code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Alex points out, `document.createElement` creates an `HTMLScriptElement` object.

You can test that the `HTMLScriptElement` was created properly by checking its properties using `expect.objectContaining`:

```
const doFunction = () => {
  const s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = 'https://myscript';
  s.id = 'abc';

  document.body.appendChild(s);
}

test('doFunction', () => {
  jest.spyOn(document.body, 'appendChild');

  doFunction();

  expect(document.body.appendChild).toBeCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      type: 'text/javascript',
      src: 'https://myscript/',
      id: 'abc'
    })
  ); // Success!
});
```

Comment: Nice - I like this approach as it tests more of the code, and in conjunction with  `expect.any(HTMLScriptElement)` it tests everything I need

Comment: Hello @ChristopherMoore I am getting this ERROR ==>  Expected: ObjectContaining {"id": "script1", "src": "app/components/myse/quoteandorderconfirmation/script/script1.js", "type": "text/javascript"}
Received: <script id="script1" src="app/components/myse/quoteandorderconfirmation/script/script1.js" type="text/javascript" />.. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

You can assert that `appendChild` is called with an HTML element, which is what `document.createElement` returns.

```
expect(document.body.appendChild).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(HTMLElement));
```

You can further clarify your test by checking that it was called with a script element.

```
expect(document.body.appendChild).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(HTMLScriptElement));
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is any way to inspect the HTMLScriptElement that is called with? e.g. to verify the `src` field is what I expect

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use jest's (optionally `inline`)`snapshots`:

```js
it('...', () => {
  doFunction()
  expect(document.documentElement).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <!-- ...your appended nodes... -->
        </head>
        <body>
          <!-- ...your appended nodes... -->
        </body>
      </html>
    `)
})
```